# Is a surface of revolution from sine curve space packing?

Tags: geometry

Is a 3D array of sine curve-based surface of revolution space packing? image below as reference for the geometry. Is there a more specific term for this geometry?

[image]

Comment: Hint: try drawing cross sections at a few different horizontal planes.

Comment: Puzzling question... By the way, which drawing tool did you use for your nice figure ?